# Change visa card type without changing number

Tags: credit-card

Is it generally possible to change a credit card from one "specialty" to another, **without changing the credit card number or expiry date**?

For example, is it possible to switch from a [TD Drivers Rewards Visa](http://www.tdcanadatrust.com/tdvisa/drivers_rewards.jsp) card to a [TD Platinum Travel Visa](http://www.tdcanadatrust.com/tdvisa/platinumtravel.jsp) card? Or, if TD Bank doesn't allow this, would you generally expect banks to allow this sort of change?

Obviously, you cannot change from a visa card to a mastercard; this necessarily would involve changing the credit card number. Also, for the sake of this academic exercise, assume the person switching would qualify for the new card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on if a new card would share the same [bank identification number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bank_Identification_Numbers).   The first digits of your credit card identify what bank issues the card.    Looking over the list on wikipedia, some banks have multiple numbers based on card type.  If that is the case, you would need a new number.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like I'd most likely be out of luck, then. Grumble grumble. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Every Card type comes with its set of reward and other features.
Today the systems that are in Bank are not geared up to change the type and keep the card number same. The reason being that for newer transactions they can still do it, however the historical transactions will become a mess, for example the rewards points calculated using older card type etc.
Hence its easier for Banks to issue a new card number, close out the old number and transfer whatever is the balance. This is more clearner and easier for existing card Systems in Banks.
Across Banks its just not possible for lot more reasons

Comment: Just today Amex changed my Blue Cash to Blue Cash Everyday without any issue.... Several years ago when Blue Cash just came out, they changed my Blue to Blue Cash without a problem. If at some bank their systems are as horrible as you describe, maybe you should be banking elsewhere. The only reason for VISA issuer not to be able to do that is the BIN issue explained by @Alex.